# MacOS High Sierra VSCode "Writing login information to the keychain failed with error 'UNIX[No such file or directory]'."

Tags: macos, keychain, login, settings, visual-studio-code

- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 with new install of VSCode 1.50.0
- Attempt to "Sign-in to Sync Settings"

  [image]
- web/browser-based SSO redirects to Microsoft and/or Github browser login
- login fails - error message in VSCode:

> `Writing login information to the keychain failed with error 'UNIX[No such file or directory]'.`

New install of VSCode on MacOS
[image]

And MacOS info:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

This is a keychain error which look similar to some others upon Google search, but I didn't find this exact error... so, adding the solution here...

**SOLUTION**

1. Attempt to "Sync Settings" by logging into Microsoft or Github
2. this will fail as OP states... but
3. close ALL instances/windows of VSCode
4. RESTART VSCode
5. You should be prompted for Apple KeyChain permissions like this image shows:
   [image]
6. Type in your MacOS `root` password
7. You will either immediately login without error(s) ... or....
8. RESTART VSCode AGAIN
9. "Sync Settings" / login once more